# Fix navigation bar after scrolling to first section using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, sticky

I want my navigation bar to become sticky after I scroll to where the first section ID is placed (think of a single page website, I want the navigation to become fixed as the person scrolls to the first "section")

Here's my HTML so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navGUI" role="navigation">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.svg" width="183px" height="65px" alt="logo" class="topLogo"></a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#section-1">Quienes Somos</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#">Productos</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#">Proyectos</a></li>
          <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#">Contáctenos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Please see the bootstrap docs for more information